# How do I add parent keys in jq

Tags: json, object, jq

I want to promote a value from inside an array element to be the parent key for the entire element.

Input:

```
[
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "value1": "fooval1",
        "value2": "fooval2"
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "value1": "barval1",
        "value2": "barval2"
    }
]
```

Output:

```
{
    "foo":{
        "value1": "fooval1",
        "value2": "fooval2"
    },
    "bar":{
        "value1": "barval1",
        "value2": "barval2"
    }
}
```

To start with, I wanted to just add .name as a parent key to each entry. But this doesnt' work:

`jq 'map(.name: {.})'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I add parent keys ?

Easily, at least once the syntax errors in the input file have been fixed.
The key is to wrap parentheses around `.name` to form the new key:

```
map( {(.name): del(.name)} )
```

Comment: Thank you, the parenthesis were indeed what I was missing

Comment: I struggled with this problem and found the accepted solution above doesn't return an object (as the initial question requested) but an array of objects ([example](https://jqplay.org/s/MJhRKZQKBau)). I needed a single object returned. I found that using `map( {(.name): del(.name)} ) | add` did the trick, as seen [here](https://jqplay.org/s/Z7OcBX3m5YC)